# question about spaces where the "vectors" are functions.

Tags: linear-algebra

> The cosine space $F_3$ contains all combinations $y(x) = A\cos x+B\cos 2x+C\cos 3x$. Find a basis for the subspace with $y(0) = 0$.

I know $y(0) = 0$ requires $A + B + C = 0$. What next? I am not familiar with spaces where the "vectors" are functions. I just think I can set $A$ to be $1$, and $B$ be $0$, $C$ be $-1$. So my answer is $(1,0,-1)$.

**But the solution is one basis is $\cos x − \cos 2x$ and $\cos x − \cos 3x$.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that it is equivalent to solve the problem $A + B + C = 0$, which is equivalent to finding a basis for the null space of the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$
but since this matrix is already in reduced row echolon form we can immediately read of a basis of the null space to be
$$(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1  \end{pmatrix}) $$
Transforming back to the vector space that we are working with, these correspond to the functions $\cos(x)-\cos(2x)$ and $\cos(x) - \cos(3x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Any vector in the subspace can be written as$$-(B+C)\cos x+B\cos 2x+C\cos 3x=B(\cos 2x-\cos x)+C(\cos 3x-\cos x)$$i.e. linear combination of $y_1(x)=\cos x-\cos2x$ and $y_2(x)=\cos x-\cos 3x$. Now all that remains is to prove the linear independence of $y_1,y_2$. Are you familiar with proving linear independence of functions?

Comment: Yes. how to prove B=C=0?

Comment: $B,C$ are arbitrary constants from the field...they are not necessarily $0$.

Comment: then how do you show $y_1,y_2$ is linear independent?

Comment: Suppose $c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x)=0\forall x\in\Bbb R$. This means $c_1y_1(\pi/2)+c_2y_2(\pi/2)=0$ and $c_1y_1(\pi)+c_2y_2(\pi)=0$. You can calculate $y_1(\pi/2),y_2(\pi/2)$ etc. which will give you a linear system in $c_1,c_2$. Solve the linear system to obtain $c_1=c_2=0$.